# JavaScript Resolution

Tags: javascript, screen, resolution

I want to run equal columns script only for resolution over 768 of width but I'm not sure how can I do it.

This is my script:

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) {
   var tallestcolumn = 0;
   columns.each(function () {
      currentHeight = $(this).height();
      if (currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
         tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
      }
   });
   columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   setEqualHeight($(" .container > .content"));
});
```

Comment: For a screen under that size or a viewport under that size?

Comment: Can you read your own code? -1 for not formatting it

Comment: So, that's how it was like to program before TAB was invented. `:P` http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3s76k0/

Comment: Oh, thanks for edit. As for question - for a screen under that (768) size.

Comment: If you could, make the title more specific for people searching to solve a similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.max is already provided by javascript to find the max of multiple values, so I would suggest using that. I'd also suggest creating a simple javascript plugin to do it.

```
$.fn.equalHeights = function () {
    if (screen.width >= 768) {
        var heights = [];
        this.each(function () {
            heights.push($(this).height());
        });
        this.height(Math.max.apply(null, heights));
    }
};

$(function () {
    $('div').equalHeights();
});​
```

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it defenitely doesn't work.

P.S It should be 'window.width => 768'.

Comment: I just realized Math.max doesn't support arrays, so I did Math.max.apply, which allows me to pass the array as arguments. Updated code (plus the screen width requirement). Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JNZen/